# Charts not using full height in Vaadin's VerticalLayout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

In exploring Vaadin 23.4.7 and using Vaadin's starter routine, I tried to add a chart to a vertical layout. However, no matter what I tried, the chart would only take half the vertical size. See screenshot below. I want it to use the full vertical height available. I tried "chart.setFullSize()" and "vlRoot.setFullSize()" etc, but it didn't work. Thoughts? (I feel that this problem existed in earlier versions of Vaadin too when trying to add charts, but that this problem does not appear if it's NOT a chart element that one is adding to a layout). (Note: The chart only gets produced after the user clicks on the "Plot" button, so essentially, there is no chart initially in the vertical layout....)

[image: screenshot of chart on vertical layout]

My code snippet is as follows:

```
 if (chart != null) {
            vlRoot.remove(chart);
        }
        chart = new Chart(ChartType.LINE);
        vlRoot.add(chart);
}
```

Vaadin Details -->

```
Flow: 24.3.7
Vaadin: 24.3.7
Java: Eclipse Adoptium 21.0.1
OS: amd64 Linux 5.15.0-1053-gcp
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Live reload: Java active
          (Spring Boot Devtools): Front end active
```